# Change DjangoMPTT admin model name

Tags: django, django-mptt

I have the following MPTTModel and admin.py:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

```
admin.site.register(infoModels.Category)
```

When I am at the admin page the model appears as "Categorys", how can I change that to be "Categories"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just your usual [`Model.Meta.verbose_name_plural`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural).

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    # ...
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
```

Be sure to not use capitalization in there (unless there's e.g. an acronym that needs to be capitalized (e.g. `FTP servers`)); Django will take care of that for you.